# Python - 2*N matrix

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

How do I create a 2*N matrix in Python, where N is undefined? Like

```
[[x,y],
 [x,y],
 [x,y],
 ...,
 [x,y]]
```

N must be updated when necessited.

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

```py
def create_2_n_matrix(n, x, y):
  return [[x,y] for i in range(n)]
create_2_n_matrix(5,1,2) # [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: I think you didn't really get my qustion...  I need a matrix which  2nd dimension is not pre-defined, but it gotta be updatet at the occurrency.

Comment: Yes that is what I did. Use `create_2_n_matrix` "at the occurrency". What's wrong?

Comment: I explained myself in the wrong way probably...
I'm creating like a "server", and the matrix must contain couples of connections.
For example, making cn = connection:
   *[[c1,c2],
 [c3,c4],
 [c5,c6],
 ...,
 [c9,c10]]*

When new connections come, the matrix must become larger. So it has no maximus size... I don't know If I explained myself well enough.